Which is more electronegative, deuterium or hydrogen
There has not been a clear answer found so I am asking here - which is more electronegative or which would display a greater electronegativity in compounds H2O and D2O and why - deuterium or protium. Sources say it is more electronegative but then It gives into more problems like then how Deuterium oxide displays more polarity

Why is the D nucleus more attractive to an electron?

Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/20405/4945

@Jon Custer posts on stack exchange say that deuterium 1s shows stronger attraction to nucleus annoyingly without explanation

@Mithoron It doesn't answer my question of whether it behaves like a more electronegative or less electornegative atom

It also says deuterium is more electronegative yet counterintuitively, has more positive inductive effect

The stronger attraction is due slighly shorter mean distance, due position of the barycenter closer to the nucleus. Similarly, but with a much bigger difference, an electron is much weaker attracted to a positron in positronium in spite of the same charges. But due the same mass, their mean distance is much bigger that for an electron and a proton.

What kind of electronegativity? There are several different ones https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity

Additionally, the most frequently used Pauling electronegativity is bond dependent.

"Sources say it is more electronegative but" What sources? And which one is more electronegative?

@Poutnik I am comparing them in H - O and D - O bond.https://byjus.com/question-answer/out-of-the-three-isotopes-of-hydrogen-which-is-more-electronegitive-and-why/ and https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/cphc.201900839#:~:text=The%20traditional%20%E2%80%9Corgan-ic%E2%80%9D%20view%20is%20simply%20that%20deuterium,justify%20rigorously%20but%20does%20rationalize%20many%20experimental%20observations.

Consider consequences of lower zero point vibration energy of O-D bond.

I know one would be that bond shorter and stronger but how does that relate to the question
